# Placing a link inside a Flex Grid?

Tags: apache-flex

How can I place a link inside a Flex Grid?

Answer (score 2):

Using navigateToURL (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/passingarguments_086_10.html), create a button component, which you can place inside the grid (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/containers/Grid.html), and call navigateToURL on click.